# Session configuration choices to be used in app in web farm

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, session

There is this question which asks the following in a particular textbook:

"You are designing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that uses an Oracle database for persistence. What session configuration choices enable you to deploy your application on a web farm?"

The answer choices of the question are :
A) InProc
B) SQLServer
C) StateServer
D) Custom session provider

The correct answers as stated are C) State Server and D) Custom Session Provider.

From what I learnt in MSDN, SQLServer mode allows for session to be used for applications in web farms too. Hence was wonder what is actually the correct answer here? Thanks.

Comment: Read the question carefully: the site isn't using SQLServer for persistence, so SQLServer is not an option. If the site were using SQLServer, then this would also be included in the correct answers.

Comment: Cool. You are right. Missed out that bit. Thanks @competent_tech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Oracle, which is a different RDBMS from SQL Server, therefore the given answers of C) and D) are actually correct.